# How to solve ASEC_CREATE permission?

Tags: android

I can´t deploy my project in my cell phone anymore. I don´t know if it is because I have updated Gradle or update my cell phone system or both.

The error message is this:

```
Error installing split apks: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Failed to finalize session : Unknown failure (Error: java.lang.SecurityException: Requires android.permission.ASEC_CREATE permission)
Error while Installing APKs
```

I have given ASEC_CREATE permission in AndroidManifest.xml with

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ASEC_CREATE"/>
```

But this does not solve the error.

I've read almost all the link about this but no luck.  Any ideas to help me solve this?

Comment: Looks weird but this permission does not seem to be a permission to my program to be able to run but a permission to Android Studio to be able to deploy my program in there. 
That's why does not make any difference if i put permission in Manifest or not.

I generated a APK in my destop upload it in my cell phone and it runs as always. 

So what this message from Android Studio means?

Comment: This problem also happens to me.
I solve this problem by updating apps from the google playstore and reconnecting the device. I think the problem is the phone.
Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 2):

This problem appeared to me when I upgraded Android Studio and then Gradle.

To solve the problem I returned the version of Gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects / modules.

Buildscript {
     Repositories {
         Jcenter ()
     }
     Dependencies {
          classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.x.x'
          ...
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the problem and after searching for long.

I found out, In my case, it was because of low memory space on my device.
It may be the case for you also.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs due to android device issue. Change your testing device to run your app.
It worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem while trying to launch the app on my phone through android studio.
I solved this by changing my mobile setting.
***settings* > *storage* > *preferred install location* > *Internal device storage*.**