# Why does my android app crash when installed on real devices giving the following exception?

Tags: android

I'm building an android app which when deployed on my emulator works absolutely fine. But when the app is installed on other real devices, the app crashes with the following exception. Please help me out.

```
03-21 18:41:40.267 3979-3979/? E/Pm: Error
                                 java.lang.SecurityException: Requires android.permission.ASEC_CREATE permission
                                     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1540)
                                     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1493)
                                     at android.content.pm.IPackageInstaller$Stub$Proxy.openSession(IPackageInstaller.java:318)
                                     at com.android.commands.pm.Pm.runInstallWrite(Pm.java:1076)
                                     at com.android.commands.pm.Pm.run(Pm.java:155)
                                     at com.android.commands.pm.Pm.main(Pm.java:100)
                                     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
                                     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:249)
 03-21 18:41:40.947 4000-4000/? E/linker: do_android_get_LD_LIBRARY_PATH           buffer_size: 4096 

 03-21 18:41:41.057 4000-4000/? E/Pm: Error
                                 java.lang.SecurityException: Requires android.permission.ASEC_CREATE permission
                                     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1540)
                                     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1493)
                                     at android.content.pm.IPackageInstaller$Stub$Proxy.openSession(IPackageInstaller.java:318)
                                     at com.android.commands.pm.Pm.runInstallAbandon(Pm.java:1138)
                                     at com.android.commands.pm.Pm.run(Pm.java:165)
                                     at com.android.commands.pm.Pm.main(Pm.java:100)
                                     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
                                     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:249)
 03-21 18:41:43.897 184-184/? E/upi_ug31xx: [event_loop]: uevent_request = 21 (1074)
```

Comment: You probably are not asking for runtime permissions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve ASEC\_CREATE permission?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35091255/how-to-solve-asec-create-permission)

Comment: @MuratK. please tell how to ask the runtime permission

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: not working....

Comment: @NISHANTBARANWAL Saying "not working" won't help. You need to post what you have tried.

Comment: @Malik, the question isn't duplicated. I have the same problem and the answer from Carl Ramos is the correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

you have to disable the instant Run on:

Settings> Build, Executions,Deployment> Instant Run

Disable instant Run

I had the same problem.. this android studio update 2.3 came with this error
Sorry for my english.. its not my native language