# Error installing APK - android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

While installing APK, I found Application installation failed with unknown failure of `ASEC_CREATE` permission ?
I am not able to install either in emulator or in any of the devices (not for particular device.)

ERROR IMAGE

[image: ERROR IMAGE]

Things I have tried:

1. Uninstalled APK from all the device and tried to reinstall.
2. I have tried by terminal using commands (for MAC OS):

   ```
   export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk
   export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
   adb uninstall package_name
   adb install //drag and drop apk build in output->apk->debug->app-debug.apk
   ```

Comment: add `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'` whatever your studio's version in your project dependency

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve ASEC\_CREATE permission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35091255/how-to-solve-asec-create-permission)

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava I am not facing problem with split apk so possibly it's not possible duplicate